# Why Prophet returns negative prediction whan inputs are all positive?

Tags: python, time-series, forecast, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to forecast with Facebook Prophet, the input are all positive but the predictions returns negative. I'm kind of confused, i read this [quick start](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html) and if the inputs are all positive then the predictions will be likely all positive and the shape of the prediction is similar like the input e.g if input is 0.86 then the output would be 0.81. Why is it like this? How to fix it?

```
covid_pr = covid[['date','acc_confirmed']].copy()
covid_pr.rename(columns = {'date':'ds', 'acc_confirmed':'y'},inplace= True)

prt = Prophet()
prt.fit(covid_pr)

future_prt = prt.make_future_dataframe(30)
forecast = prt.predict(future_prt)
```

My input data

```
           ds     y
0  2020-03-02     2
1  2020-03-03     2
2  2020-03-04     2
3  2020-03-05     2
4  2020-03-06     4
5  2020-03-07     4
6  2020-03-08     6
7  2020-03-09    19
8  2020-03-10    27
9  2020-03-11    34
10 2020-03-12    34
etc until thousands
```

Prediction of fbprophet

```
     yhat   yhat_lower   yhat_upper
0   -261.572541  -499.409024    -4.741004
1   -208.490561  -446.503629    41.371788
2   -255.114682  -500.580393    -7.825269
3   -208.963597  -481.238870    33.707433
4   -146.566250  -394.337188    96.726382
5    -92.445918  -354.914790   150.409867
6    -38.341696  -293.639411   204.964963
7     83.483534  -158.412231   332.263619
8    136.565514   -95.174934   370.980615
9     89.941393  -153.219255   349.129866
10   136.097121   -95.508485   404.666524
etc until thousands
```

Comment: Can you plot the data and predictions? If there's a negative trend, it is likely the predictions follow that trend (for any good model), regardless of whether that makes sense given the modelling domain. I don't see any code issues here, per se, so this might better be asked at [stats.SE].

Comment: well from the fbprohphet components, it shows that there's negative weekly seasonality

Answer (score 0):

facebook prophet saturating-minimum page is what you want to look at the.You can specify a limit even for each row.

https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html#saturating-minimum

In order to be bounded you have to use growth logistic. 
Assuming your future dataframe is called future you can specify floor column as below:

```
future['floor'] = 0
m = Prophet(growth='logistic')
m.fit(df)
result = m.predict(future)
```

Comment: oh okay, this is my first time using the fbprophet i already read that link you give and also this [very similar link](https://nextjournal.com/clojurework/saturating-forecasts). but i do not understand why saturating-minimum would be my solution. could you explain it a bit for me?